# Как получить значения словаря

Tags: python

я новичок в python. у меня есть словарь полученный из json:

```
        result = [
                  { 
                    "a": 111, 
                    "b": 222, 
                    "c": {
                           "a": 1111, 
                           "b": "2222", 
                           "c": "3333"
                          }
                  }
                 ]
```

как сделать чтобы выводилось только значения третей переменой ("c":{....}) словаря, помогите плиз.

Вот что я попытался сделать но это не то.

```
for row in result:
    for elem in row:
        print(elem, end = ' ')
    print()
```

Comment: `result[0]["c"]`

Comment: Приведите пример ожидаемых данных.

Comment: пример: [( "a": 1111, "b": "2222", "c": "3333")]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 

```
for key in result[0]:
    print(result[0][key])
```

Вывод:

```
111
222
{'a': 1111, 'b': '2222', 'c': '3333'}
```

2. 

```
for key in result[0]['c']:
    print(result[0]['c'][key])
```

Вывод:

```
1111
2222
3333
```

Пробуй, эксперементируй.

Answer (score 2):

```
print(result[0]["c"])
```